# Cosmos DB composite index best practices?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I've got some pretty high Cosmos usage right now that I'd like to reduce, and I think the way to do that is through composite indices, but I'm a little confused about the best approach.

My actual queries get more complex than this, but let's say I have 2 queries that look like this:

```
SELECT TOP 100 * FROM c WHERE c.partitionkey=n AND c.data.subdata1="str1" ORDER BY c._ts DESC
SELECT TOP 100 * FROM c WHERE c.partitionkey=n AND c.data.subdata1="str1" AND c.data.subdata2="str2" ORDER BY c._ts DESC
```

If I create a composite index that looks like this, will it help? Should I create two separate indices, one for each query? Should I put the partitionkey into the composite index, even though I'll only ever be searching on a single partition?

```
"compositeIndexes":[  
    [  
        {  
            "path":"/data/subdata1",
            "order":"ascending"
        },
        {  
            "path":"/_ts",
            "order":"descending"
        }
    ]
]
```

Comment: Are there any index on subdata1 and subdata2?

Comment: I've left the default indexing policy on, which should index everything apart from the etag field

Comment: Do you see big RU difference when you remove Order BY c._ts DESC ?

Comment: Good shout, yes it's less that a 10th of the RUs if I remove the ORDER BY clause (~70 RUs as opposed to ~780 RUs with the ordering) and that's despite the fact that I have set up the composite index above which includes the the descending timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

In Cosmos DB, composite indexes will have a performance benefit for queries that have a multiple filters or both a filter and an ORDER BY clause. So in your case, I think the composite index will help.

> Should I put the partitionkey into the composite index, even though
> I'll only ever be searching on a single partition?

I believe that put the partitionkey into the composite index will improve performance of your SQL, although you search on a single partition.

The best practice is to test your SQL with different composite indexes in Azure Cosmos DB Emulator, and according to the Query Status to decide which to use.

Comment: Yeah, ideally I'd experiment and iterate, but I have 1.6TB of data, and reindexing that takes hours. So I was hoping to get a better understanding of the underlying workings to try to optimise my indexes.

Comment: "I believe that put the partitionkey into the composite index will improve performance of your SQL, although you search on a single partition." Would you have a link to some sort of documentation supporting this claim. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have 2 composite indexes
First one should have partitionkey, subdata1 and _ts
Second one should have partitionkey, subdata2 and _ts

If your data is too large and you don't want to re-index, I would suggest to remove ORDER BY in database level and move it to your code.